# Default homepage for specialized search engine

Tags: user-interface, search-engine, user-experience

I have a domain-specific, specialized search engine. The home page of the site presents the results of a default query which makes sense in my context. In other words, when a user lands on my page, he immediately sees the result of an interesting query.

My other option is to present the user a very simplistic welcome page with a textbox and button (like the modern general-purpose search engines of today) and force him to interact with the site before he sees any results. The logic that someone who issues at least one query and interact with the site will likely to issue other queries as well.

Can anyone tell me about the pros and cons of those two different default behaviors?

My object is make people interact with the site, issue queries and share the result of those queries with other people. I believe the answer depends on the nature of my users. I'd like to hear people with experiences on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have read about these sort of user-interface questions is 'let the evidence show you that way'.

Several ideas come to mind,

Label your site as 'beta', then

- make 2 pages, and then serve them randomly as users hit your page.
- show both ideas on one page.
- show 1 option with a link and explanatory text to the other option.

Track the users follow-on behavior. Rethink, redesign, remold your system to optimize the results (which you are so secretive about ;-) ) that canbe  achieved.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I believe "letting users decide" is the ideal way to solve this problem, but I doubt that I will ever have a large enough user base to carry out such experiments with precision. I am also hoping to hear about the experiences of other people to make an informed -- albeit, possibly, wrong -- decision in my case :) BTW, it's a political text seearch engine in my native language. There's nothing secret about it -- just didn't want it to get in the way.